# Upper bound on ratio of incomplete Gamma function and Gamma function $\frac{ \Gamma \left( x; a\right)}{\Gamma(x)}$

Tags: integration, approximation, gamma-function

I am trying to find a tight upper bound the following expression 
\begin{align}
\frac{ \Gamma \left( x; a\right)}{\Gamma(x)}
\end{align}
where  $\Gamma \left( x; a\right)$ is incomplet Gamma function
\begin{align}
\Gamma \left( x; a\right)= \int_{a}^\infty  t^{x-1} e^{-t} dt.
\end{align}

Also, assume $x \ge 1/2$.
Clearly a trivial upper bound is
\begin{align}
\frac{ \Gamma \left( x; a\right)}{\Gamma(x)} \le 1
\end{align}

However, I suspect the following bound should be true

\begin{align}
\frac{ \Gamma \left( x; a\right)}{\Gamma(x)} \le O( e^{-a} )
\end{align}

Comment: You've given a lower bound on $x$.  Do you have any bounds on $a$?

Comment: @EricTowers I want a general bound that holds for any $a$ and $x$ without any assumption on $x$ and $a$. In fact, I would like to vary $a$ not $x$.

Comment: Then this is hopeless.  For $x<0$, this ratio is unbounded.

Comment: @EricTowers Still with assumption $x>1/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_{a}^{+\infty}t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt = e^{-a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}(t+a)^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt\leq e^{-a}a^{x-1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(\frac{t(x-1)}{a}-t\right)\,dt$$
hence a simple upper bound is:
$$ \Gamma(x;a)\leq \frac{a^x e^{-a}}{a+1-x}.$$
That approximation can be refined, producing a [continued fraction representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/10/) for the incomplete $\Gamma$ function:
$$ \Gamma(x;a) = \frac{a^x e^{-a}}{a+\frac{1-x}{1+\frac{1}{a+\frac{2-x}{\ldots}}}}$$
Have also a look at [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0501019).

Comment: ?? that's not what is asked

Comment: If $a+1-x<0$ then the bound is negative, right? This doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: Obviously it is an approximation that holds for large $a$s.

Answer (score 2):

Your final inequality seems to be false.  For instance, $\dfrac{\Gamma(2;a)}{\Gamma(2)} = (a+1)\mathrm{e}^{-a}$ and $\dfrac{\Gamma(3;a)}{\Gamma(3)} = \dfrac{1}{2}(a^2 + 2a + 2)\mathrm{e}^{-a}$.  The bound $\dfrac{\Gamma(x;a)}{\Gamma(x)} \leq O(a^{x-1}\mathrm{e}^{-a})$ seems possible, but I haven't taken the time to find a proof.

Comment: Thank you. In case you are curios, please do take the time.

Comment: For example how would you compute $\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{\Gamma(n;n)}{\Gamma(n)}$ ?

Comment: @Boby: that limit is $\frac{1}{2}$ by a famous probabilistic argument: you are computing the probability that a limit random variable (fulfilling the hyphotesis of the central limit theorem) takes a value that is less than its expected value.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you. What aboutn $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Gamma(n,\lambda n)}{\Gamma(n)}$. Is it $0$ if $\lambda>1$ and $1$ if $\lambda<1$ ?

Comment: @Boby: yes, you're right. In such cases it is enough to use some concentration inequality for the Gamma distribution, whose mean and variance are known. You may also replace the Gamma distribution with a normal distribution and prove the same: the Central Limit Theorem allow us to do so.

Comment: A non-trivial limit is $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n,n+\lambda\sqrt{n})}{\Gamma(n)}$, but it can be found through the same lines.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio One more question. Is there a sense of how fast these limits decay. For example, can  we show that they decay faster than any polynomial that is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Gamma(n,\lambda n)}{\Gamma(n)}$ goes to $0$ if $\lambda>1$ and $1$ if $\lambda<1$? Thank you.

Comment: @Boby: I am not able to understand your last question exactly. What do you want to show that exhibits a faster-than-polynomial decay?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry, typo. Can we show that $ \lim_{n  \to \infty} \frac{n^{k} \Gamma(n, \lambda n)}{\Gamma(n)}$ goes to $0$ if $\lambda>1$ and $1$ if $\lambda<1$ for any $k \ge 0$??

Comment: @Boby: oh, yes. The technique is always the same: concentration inequalities for a suitable distribution. Plenty of tight bounds are known in the Gaussian case, while Hoeffding's and Azuma's inequalities cover more general cases.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry, I take it back for $\lambda<1$  $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k \Gamma(n,\lambda n)}{\Gamma(n)} = \infty$. Since, $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \Gamma(n,\lambda n)}{\Gamma(n)} =1$